# Bash Script: sed/awk/regex to match an IP address and replace

Tags: regex, replace, sed, awk

I have a string in a bash script that contains a line of a log entry such as this:

```
Oct 24 12:37:45 10.224.0.2/10.224.0.2 14671: Oct 24 2012 12:37:44.583 BST: %SEC_LOGIN-4-LOGIN_FAILED: Login failed [user: root] [Source: 10.224.0.58] [localport: 22] [Reason: Login Authentication Failed] at 12:37:44 BST Wed Oct 24 2012
```

To clarify; the first IP listed there "10.224.0.2" was the machine the submitted this log entry, of a failed login attempt. Someone tried to log in, and failed, from the machine at the 2nd IP address in the log entry, "10.224.0.58".

I wish to replace the first occurrence of the IP address "10.224.0.2" with the host name of that machine, as you can see presently is is "IPADDRESS/IPADDRESS" which is useless having the same info twice. So here, I would like to `grep` (or similar) out the first IP and then pass it to something like the `host` command to get the reverse host and replace it in the log output.

I would like to repeat this for the 2nd IP "10.224.0.58". I would like to find this IP and also replace it with the host name.

It's not just those two specific IP address though, any IP address. So I want to search for 4 integers between 1 and 3, separated by 3 full stops '.'

Is regex the way forward here, or is that over complicating the issue?

Many thanks.

Comment: Do you want any IP address or this specific one?

Comment: You need to provide some better sample input, the expected output from that input, an explanation of why you want to find those 2 specific IP addresses in a file when you already know them, and what you mean by "a variable" - a shell variable, an awk variable?  something else? What command do you use to do a "reverse lookup"?

Comment: I have updated the question, hopefully this has clarified my requirements

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Replace a fixed IP address with a host name:

```
$ cat log | sed -r 's/10\.224\.0\.2/example.com/g'
```

Replace all IP addresses with a host name:

```
$ cat log | sed -r 's/[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}/example.com/g'
```

If you want to call an external program, it's easy to do that using Perl (just replace `host` with your lookup tool):

```
$ cat log | perl -pe 's/(\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3})/`host \1`/ge'
```

Hopefully this is enough to get you started.

Answer (score 1):

There's variou ways to find th IP addresses, here's one. Just replace "printf '<<<%s>>>' " with "host" or whatever your command name is in this GNU awk script:

```
$ cat tst.awk
{
    subIp = gensub(/\/.*$/,"","",$4)
    srcIp = gensub(/.*\[Source: ([^]]+)\].*/,"\\1","")

    "printf '<<<%s>>>' " subIp | getline subName
    "printf '<<<%s>>>' " srcIp | getline srcName

    gsub(subIp,subName)
    gsub(srcIp,srcName)

    print
}
$
$ gawk -f tst.awk file
Oct 24 12:37:45 <<<10.224.0.2>>>/<<<10.224.0.2>>> 14671: Oct 24 2012 12:37:44.583 BST: %SEC_LOGIN-4-LOGIN_FAILED: Login failed [user: root] [Source: <<<10.224.0.58>>>] [localport: 22] [Reason: Login Authentication Failed] at 12:37:44 BST Wed Oct 24 2012
```

Answer (score 0):

googled this one line command together. but was unable to pass the founded ip address to the ssh command:

```
sed -n 's/\([0-9]\{1,3\}\.\)\{3\}[0-9]\{1,3\}/\nip&\n/gp' test | grep ip | sed 's/ip//' |   sort | uniq
```

the "test" is the file the sed command is searching for for the pattern